# Check if the current time falls in this range?

Tags: javascript

I have a below  `"start":"23:00" and "end":"24:00"`. 
I want to check whether the current time falls in between them.

I have the below code, which works fine for `Eastern time zone`, but does not work in other `time zones`.

```
isBetween(start, end) {
  var d = new Date();
  var time = (d.getHours()) + ":" (d.getMinutes());   
  return time >= start && time <= end;
}
```

How do i convert my `start` and `end` to local timezone and then do the comparison? I am getting the time in EDT from server.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```js
 function isBetweenHours(startHour, endHour)
    {
        var now = new Date().getHours();
        return now >= parseInt(startHour, 10) && now <= parseInt(endHour, 10);
    }
    
    //Then you would use it like this:
    
    if( isBetweenHours('23:00', '24:00') ) {
        console.log('It is in between!!');
    } else {
        console.log('It is not in the range!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting your `start` and `end` to the local timezone, I suggest to do the other way round :) Adjust the local time to UTC time and compare with that. Keep your `start` and `end` accordingly as well. Something like this:

```js
isBetween(start, end) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMinutes(d.getTimezoneOffset());
  var time = (d.getHours()) + ":" (d.getMinutes());   
  return time >= start && time <= end;
}
```